# Clear Datagram Buffer in Java

Tags: java, udp, buffer, byte

So I got this simple udp client/server code from the internet, and it works.  However, when I enter something that is shorter than the thing I entered before it, I get the remaining characters left over.  For example, if I first enter:

```
kitty
```

And then enter:

```
cat
```

The second print reads as:

```
catty
```

I've been looking at other people with similar problems and most of them seem to be solved by clearing the byte array.  However, if I try to implement their answers, it doesn't fix my problem.  What do I need to do, and (maybe more importantly) where in the code should it go?  Here is the code:

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
       BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
       InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
       byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
       byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
       String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
       sendData = sentence.getBytes();
       DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 20700);
       clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
       DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
       clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
       String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
       System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
       clientSocket.close();
    }
 }
```

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class UDPServer
 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
       {
          DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(21200);
          byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
          byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
          while(true)
                {
                   DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                   serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                   String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
                   System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                   InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                   int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                   String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                   sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                   DatagramPacket sendPacket =  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                   serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to clear the byte array, but you do need to take some notice of the length of the DatagramPacket after the receive, via the `getLength()` method; for example:

```
new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

You're doing that correctly in the server, but not in the client.

You also need to reset the length before calling `receive()`. Otherwise the `DatagramPacket` will keep shrinking to the length of the smallest packet received so far.

Comment: DatagramPacket.setLength()?

Comment: @user1440061 you reset the length through:
`receivePacket.setLength(receiveData.getLength())`

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins You mean `receivePacket.setLength(receiveData.length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Greeting from the future (10 years after posted). This post asked a problem I had, so I'll tell you what I did to solve it.

In the code provided, his client closes, so the issue isn't from the client side, it's from the server side. The solution I used was putting

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
```

within the loop. This makes them local variable, so be careful not to skip them on accident. It also probably messes with memory, because it's deleting and re-initializing it every time.

Don't know if it's "best practice", but it worked so it's good for my purposes. If you also have a repeating client, you can also use this method.