# How can erase the contents of an array in Java with safety?

Tags: java

I'm trying to receive data from a client and then log it onto the console.
Here is how i do this:

```
private final int MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 1024;
private byte[] data = new byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

private void receive() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (running) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
                sPort = packet.getPort();
                ip = packet.getAddress();
                address = ip.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String messageToPrint = new String(packet.getData());
            System.out.println(messageToPrint.trim() + " " + address + " | " + sPort);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

When it comes to printing my `messageToPrint` it actually repeats the last one, and reprinting it with a newer one.

I've figured out what is the problem though.

If i put allocation of the array `data` inside the `while` loop, everything works fine and i don't get the previous message again, just current one.

I don't really want to do this, because allocation inside loops not a good idea so i need somehow to clear my array before new data comes in.

The output without allocation inside the loop is:

```
Console: past message

Console: (imagine i typed hello) hellomessage
```

and so on.

Comment: `Arrays.fill()`? But I doubt that will be much faster than allocating a new array

Comment: Not sure ... but did you also try to make *packet* a field of your enclosing class?

Comment: Or maybe; does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549195/clear-datagram-buffer-in-java ?

Comment: @GhostCat good point though and seems like i did just that.

Comment: Fell free to accept flikes answer then; and maybe, if you want to upvote some any other answer of mine for giving making the initial suggestion ;-)

Comment: @Zal Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the packet outside of the loop, and also retrieve size data from the packet. *(Otherwise you'll print the entire array which could contain the trailing text of the last message received)*

```
final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
while (running) {
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        ...
    final String messageToPrint = new String(
            packet.getData(), 
            packet.getOffset(), 
            packet.getLength());
    ...
```

Comment: but what was the actual reason for op's issue and why does this solve it? how does it work?